# How to add XML tags to an XML document from posted data?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to write a web-based data visualisation app that allows users to load in a txt file, autoparse it to xml, view it on the screen, right-click on the text and assign a tag to all counts of the selected word.

Currently upon right click, I pass to the PHP handler: element name to be added, the attribute name to be added, the value to be added, the files name, and the selected word. I have all of these available in the handler, but after several hours of searching I cannot figure out how to add the tag element/attribute/value to the selected word in the XML file.

*php file*

```
<?php

$target_dir = "../UserFiles/Files/";

//$filename = $_POST["filename"];

$filename = "Chretien 1 Erec";

//$element = $_POST["element"];

$element = "Emotion";

//$attribute = $_POST["attribute"];

$attribute = "Type";

//$value = $_POST["value"];

$value = "Positive";

//$selection = $_POST["selection"];

$selection = "vilains";

$target_file = $target_dir . $filename . ".xml";

//if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

  $xml = file_get_contents($target_file);  

  $sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);  

  //get current xml elements

  $docElements = [];

  array_push($docElements, $sxml->getName());

  foreach ($sxml->children() as $child){

      array_push($docElements, $child->getName());

  }

  if (in_array($element, $docElements, true)) {

    echo "It's there!";

  } else {

    echo "It's not there!";

    $result = $sxml->xpath($element);

    print_r($result);

    //$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($element);

    //$sxe->addAttribute($attribute, $selection)

  }

?php>;
```

*xml file*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>;

<LiteraryWork Author="Chretian" Title="Erec" Type="Romance">

 Li vilains dit an son respit

que tel chose a l'an an despit

qui mout valt mialz que l'an ne cuide

por ce fet bien qui son estuide

atorne a bien, quel que il l'ait

car qui son estuide antrelait

tost i puet tel chose teisir

<LiteraryWork>
```

Comment: @u_mulder The semicolons shouldn't be there, that happened during the paste; I've just removed them now. The arrows are object functions for SimpleXML.

Comment: And what is not working with this code?

Comment: @u_mulder The code only outputs the elements found in the xml document. I have don't know how to iterate over the words in the xml document to find a match with the users selection so I can write an xml tag in.